# how to replace illegal characters in xml

Tags: c#, xml

I am moving some c# code into the webconfig file and I need help with some illegal characters. It is a physical path.
here is what I trying to move.

```
string ArchiveDirectory = @"C:\Users\rsanchez\Desktop\testing\" + foldername + "\\Archives\\";
```

here is web.config

```
<add key="ArchiveDirectory" value="..." />
```

[image: pic]

Comment: sorry, forgot to upload screenshot

Comment: Shouldn't your web config just have the actual path, not C# code?

Comment: im not sure, thats why i need help. even with the actual path i still run into problems with + foldername +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That string concatenation and variable replacement isn't going to work, there is no code being run in your web.config.

Introduce a placeholder:

```
<add key="ArchiveDirectory" value="C:\Users\rsanchez\Desktop\testing\{foldername}\Archives\" />
```

Then replace it in code:

```
string archiveDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ArchiveDirectory"];
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(archiveDirectory))
{
    archiveDirectory = archiveDirectory.Replace("{foldername}", foldername);
}
```